# How can I re write SQL query to LINQ 

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

This is my MS SQL Query ( I m using this as a Stored Procedure ). I am new to LINQ. I am using .NET framework 4.0 and Entity Framework.

Query 1

```
 SELECT SUM(PTS.Run1)AS Run1,SUM(PTS.Run2)AS Run2,
 SUM(PTS.Run3)AS Run3,SUM(PTS.Run4)AS Run4,SUM(PTS.Run6)AS Run6
,SUM(PTS.BallsFaced)AS BallsFaced 
     FROM PlayerTeamSeason PTS
     INNER JOIN Player P ON P.ID=PTS.PlayerId 
WHERE P.CrewId =89 and PTS.SeasonId=1
```

**EDIT 1**

I need solution for getting

- MAX value and JOIN(kindly refer Query 1)

**EDIT 2**

```
  from crew in Oritia_entities.Crews
       join P in Oritia_entities.Players on crew.ID equals P.CrewId
                                  //select new { P.ID, P.Matches };
       join PTS in Oritia_entities.PlayerTeamSeasons on P.ID equals PTS.PlayerId
        select new
       {
          TotalRuns = PTS.Run1 + PTS.Run2 + PTS.Run3 + PTS.Run4 + PTS.Run6
            ,
          Bowls = PTS.BallsFaced
                                  };
```

I had re write the query to LINQ. But how can I use SUM here. As I write in my sql query

Thanks

VeeKeyBee

Comment: Rather than posting all the work you need to do, why not post a single query representative of the knowledge you would like to learn? If there is more than one thing you don't understand, they are probably best posted as separate questions.

Comment: @RedFilter I am really new to LINQ. I don't want anyone to rewrite in to LINQ. Just expecting some tips. I am learning ASP.Net MVC and now I just created a scenario which I just get a players batting ,bowling and feilding details with a single sp. So i can avoid 3 different calls to db server. So just trying to provide my requirement in details.

Comment: Apparently we're not allowed to link to ltgtfy in comments.  Well done, SO.  Anyway, a quick google search lead me here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: @Norla   thanks for your link.why negative marks? :(

Comment: I did not mark you down.   Answered what the question might be.  It is not clear if you want the LINQ equivalent of the query or LINQ to SP that return multiple result sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Article on MSDN for SP that returns multiple result sets.  Google first.

[LINQ to SQL: returning multiple result sets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/02/04/linq-to-sql-returning-multiple-result-sets.aspx)

Comment: wow, that is a major edit,  next time be more clear the first time

Comment: i searched a lot . but i didn't get the desired links. :(

Answer (score 2):

First, run -- don't walk -- over to [LINQPad.net](http://www.linqpad.net/) and get yourself a copy of LINQPad. Also, I would recommend spending the measly $58 to get the Premium version for autocomplete.

There are some quick tutorials as well as lots of example code that can really get you started with finding out equivalent LINQ commands.

It's a very easy-to-use program that allows you to quickly run and experiment with LINQ including actually querying against your database.  It also allows you to run code and even SQL queries, which is helpful in your case because you could have your SQL queries open in one tab while you work on your corresponding LINQ queries in the other.

Secondly, the way I would start in your situation is with the output. Run your query, look at what the output is, and then try to develop your LINQ queries from that. I don't think trying to convert the actual SQL query is the easiest way, but it could still afford you some guidance.

You will find LINQ is actually very similar to SQL and the first way to think about it is that it's backwards from SQL. For example, the `select` comes at the end of LINQ. Actually, once you use LINQ for awhile you'll discover that it's SQL that is really backwards.

Let me start you out with some help:

```
SELECT @playerID= ID  FROM Player WHERE crewid=@playerID
```

In LINQ:

```
int playerID = 1234;
var result = from player in Player
             where player.crewid == playerID
             select player.ID
```

Since this is EF, you will probably have your database context in front of Player, but at least in LINQPad (though an EF connection in the program) you can develop your queries before transferring them over to your production code.

Here's an example of using LinqPad showing how you can connect to Entity Framework and how you can write some queries. Notice there are samples available.  Also notice that I wrote a couple of quick queries that might help you with your queries.

[image]